ValueError using mat73 (Size must be positive)
I'm using mat73 to load some .mat files that won't open with scipy and it says:
 File "/home/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/InputXXX.py", line 13, in <module>
    coord = mat73.loadmat(path1)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX.py", line 1, in <module>
    import XXX as XXX
ValueError: Size must be positive (size must be positive)

where
path1 = dir_name_var + "/" + case_name + "_coord_ds" + ".mat"
I don't even understand what 'size' should be positive.
It's on VS code.
When using Spyder 6, it doesn't have this problem. I prefer using VS code, though and would like to see this solved.

@skjerns can you help me with this?
